# Make words fat using function bar

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, concatenation

Is there a way in MS Excel 2013 to format words fat/thick using the function bar?

I need the concatenating function and want to highlight each cells information
with an additional section like title which should be display fat/thick.

Comment: Are you referring to something other than bold?

Comment: May be a duplicate of [Using Bold in the CONCATENATE function of excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882014/using-bold-in-the-concatenate-function-of-excel)